# want the outline of coordinates, perhaps not the convex hull

Tags: algorithm, convex-hull

I wanted a direct outline of given points on a map.  I did find a divide-and-conquer algorithm, but its results are too abstract.  I put in the coordinates of Texas and the convex hull of Texas looks nothing like the state.

I later realized I'm not looking for a convex hull, as I found this
[Convex Hull Misunderstanding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218687/convex-hull-misunderstanding)

Anyone happen to know a program that can pick out the outline points in my coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polygon that forms the state of Texas is concave and not convex. Thus you need something a bit more [generalized than the convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape).

If you are dealing purely with states, there are places where you can find the coordinates that form the polygons for them, and it's likely better to use those.

Otherwise, a place to start would be research into [alpha shapes](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Alpha_shapes_2/Chapter_main.html).

Comment: Thanks.  This really helped me get on the right track.  Alpha shapes seem really complicated to me, so I looked more for concave.